# How to attach user credentials to the request pipeline in expressjs?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to write a middleware that extracts the user model and attach it to the request pipeline.
I have already written a token extractor middleware and managed to attach the token to the request pipeline, but for some reason when I try to extract the user model, it works fine inside the middleware function yet inside my controller it returns as undefined.

Here's what I have tried:

**utils/middleware.js**

```js
const tokenExtractor = async (request, response, next) => {    
        const authorization = await request.get('authorization');
       if (authorization && authorization.toLowerCase().startsWith('bearer ')) {
         request.token = authorization.substring(7);         
       } else{
         request.token = null;
        }
        next();
};

const userExtractor = async (request, response, next) => {  
  tokenExtractor(request, response, next);
  if(request.token){
    const decodedToken = jwt.verify(request.token, process.env.SECRET);    
    request.user = await User.findById(decodedToken.id);
    console.log(request.user); // Works
    next();
  } else{
    response.status(403).json({ error: 'no token received' });
  }
};
```

Inside my controllers it breaks down:

**controllers/blogs.js**

```js
blogRouter.post("/", async (request, response, next) => {
  if (request.body.title && request.body.url) {
    const token = request.token;    
    if (!token) {
      return response.status(401).json({ error: 'invalid token' });
    }
      
    console.log(request.user); // undefined !
    if(!request.user){
      return response.status(401).json({ error: 'invalid user' });
    }
    
    const user = request.user;    
    
    const blog = new Blog({
      title: request.body.title,
      author: request.body.author,
      url: request.body.url,
      likes: request.body.likes,
      user: user._id,
    });

    
    await blog.save();    
    
    user.blogs = user.blogs.concat(blog._id);
    await user.save();
    
    response.status(201).json(blog);
  }
  response.status(400).end();
});
```

Both middleware are already attached to the express app.

**EDIT:**

I have fixed the issue by removing the call to tokenExtractor from userExtractor function, and then chaining the middleware to the router instead of calling them before everything.

I was using the tokenExtractor globaly, while the userExtractor locally to the blogsRouter. What was happening was that while the tokenExtractor was working fine, the blogRouters was being called before the userExtractor ever get called, hence why I was getting undefined.

**app.js**

```js
// app.use(tokenExtractor);
app.use(requestLogger);
app.use(errorHandler);
// app.use(userExtractor);

app.use('/api/login', tokenExtractor, loginRouter);
app.use('/api/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/api/blogs', tokenExtractor, userExtractor, blogRouter); // chaining the extractors
```

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense, let `next()` carry the `(req, res, next)` instances forward, as a *pipe*. No hacks are needed and you can stack as many middlewares as needed and even reuse values from one inside the other - if you can trust the order of the call stack.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to chain it. The callback argument for the next middleware function only needs to be specified as follows.

```
const tokenExtractor = (request, response, next) => {
  const auth = request.get('authorization')
  if (auth && auth.toLowerCase().startsWith('bearer ')) {
    request.token = auth.substring(7)
    next()
  } else {
    next()
  }
}
```